# Mutable variable and case statement in Haskell

Tags: haskell, switch-statement, mutable, case-statement

So I'm not sure if what I want is in fact a mutable variable, but it's something likened to it.

I essentially want to do this:

```
case thing of
    True -> p <- func
    False -> p <- otherFunc
return Record {program=p, otherFields=oF}
```

Any way I can do something like that? I've made my function return an IO Record, so tried just putting the return in the case statement, but my last line needs to return it, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to move where the `case` occurs:

```
p <- case thing of
        True -> func
        False -> otherFunc
return $ Record {program=p, otherFields=oF}
```

But this is assuming that `func` and `otherFunc` have the same type, namely `IO Program`, where `Program` is whatever type `p` is.

You have to do it this way because the syntax is defined (more or less) as

```
case <expr> of
    <pattern1> -> <expr1>
    <pattern2> -> <expr2>
    ...
    <patternN> -> <exprN>
```

However, the syntax `<pattern> <- <expr>` is not in itself an expression, you can't just bind a name using the `<-` syntax to get a complete expression, you have to do something with it afterwards.  Think of expressions as something that return a value, any value at all.  The `<-` syntax does not have a return value, it's extracting a value from a monadic context and assigning it to a name.  This is similar to how `let x = y` doesn't have a return value, it's just binding a value to a name.  `x` and `y` themselves have return values, but `let x = y` does not.

This is why you can't just put `p <- func` *by itself* in a case branch, it would have to have other things with it.  However, if your overall case *expression* has a return value like `IO Program`, then you can extract that using `<-`.

Pretty much all of this goes for `let` bindings as well.  If instead your `func` and `otherFunc` functions have the type `Program`, instead of `IO Program`, then you could just do

```
let p = case thing of
        True -> func
        False -> otherFunc
in Record {program=p, otherFields=oF}
```

Or more succinctly

```
Record {program=(if thing then func else otherFunc), otherFields=oF}
```

You can use `if-then-else` with monadic bind as well:

```
do
    p <- if thing then func else otherFunc
    return $ Record {program=p, otherFields=oF}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yup!

```
let p = case thing of
   ...
return ...
```

This is syntax sugar in `do` notation (itself syntax sugar) for

```
let p = case thing of
   ...
  in do
       ...
       return ...
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! You answered first, so I'll make yours correct! Only a fraction, though!

Comment: @Gentatsu, our answers are a bit different! Think about where each is appropriate.

Comment: At the core, they both say that you let a variable equal the result of a case statement, which is what I wanted, and yours made me realise that, so I feel as if you deserve it.

Comment: @Gentatsu, bheklilr's is actually saying something a bit different/more interesting. You should think about it carefully.

Comment: About the return type being the same? Yeah, I thought it was implied though? Since I wouldn't be able to put it in my record otherwise.

Comment: @Gentatsu I think the more important distinction is `<-` vs `=`.  Are `func` and `otherFunc` pure or do they have to perform `IO` to get a value?  Either way, both of our solutions reduce down to the same advice, move the case expression fully to the other side of the binding symbol.

Comment: They perform IO, so I'm using <-. Yours is correct in my context and is a fuller answer and more complete answer including a few other useful examples which also fit in to the same vein. I'll accept yours then, if it'll make you guys happy =P.